# Configuring modules with RequireJS when config depends on RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Apologies if I have missed this in the docs. Basically I want to use the RequireJS module configuration feature. I would like to centrally manage the config values given to modules in a package.

This is an example from the docs:

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        'bar': {
            size: 'large'
        },
        'baz': {
            color: 'blue'
        }
    }
});

//bar.js, which uses simplified CJS wrapping:
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    //Will be the value 'large'
    var size = module.config().size;
});

//baz.js which uses a dependency array,
define(['module'], function (module) {
    //Will be the value 'blue'
    var color = module.config().color;
});
```

My problem is that my configuration info will be a little more complex, and will itself have dependencies. I would like to do:

```
requirejs.config({
    config: {
        'bar': {
            path: path.dirname(module.uri)
            key: crypto.randomBytes(64)
        },
    }
});
```

Where variables in my config need to use requireJS to evaluate.

To me it would make sense for there to be a logical separation between the RequireJS configuration - the config necessary to load modules - and the user's module configuration. But I am currently struggling to find this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought about this a little more I have come up with a workaround. It is not particularly pretty but it does seem to work.

I simply do requireJS(...) twice, first to create the config, and second to load the application modules with the config..

```
requireJSConfig = 
    baseUrl: __dirname
    nodeRequire: require

# Create the require function with basic config
requireJS = require('requirejs').config(requireJSConfig)  
requireJS ['module', 'node.extend', 'crypto', 'path'], (module, extend, crypto, path) ->
    # Application configuration 
    appConfig =
        'bar':
            path:   path.dirname(module.uri)
            key:    crypto.randomBytes(64) # for doing cookie encryption

    # get a new requireJS function with CONFIG data
    requireJS = require('requirejs').config(extend(requireJSConfig, config: appConfig))
    requireJS ['bar'], (app) ->
        ###
            Load and start the server
        ###
        appServer = new app()

        #  And start the app on that interface (and port).
        appServer.start()
```

And in bar.coffee

```
# bar.coffee
define ['module'], (module) ->
    # config is now available in this module
    console.log(module.config().key)
```

Answer (score 6):

For this sort of solution, I would have the module depend on a "config" module that you can swap for a different one using paths config. So if "bar" needed some config, "bar.js" would look like:

```
define(['barConfig'], function (config) {
});
```

Then barConfig.js could have your other dependencies:

```
define(['crypto'], function (crypto) {
    return {
      key: crypto.randomBytes(64)
    }
});
```

Then, if you needed different configs for say, production vs. dev, use paths config to map barConfig to other values:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    barConfig: 'barConfig-prod'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to do this is to make a config module...

```
// config.js
define(['module', 'path', 'crypto'], function(module, path, crypto) {
    return {
        path: path.dirname(module.uri)
        key: crypto.randomBytes(64)
    };
});
```

Then use it in other modules...

```
// bar.js
define(['config'], function (config) {
    var key = config.key;
});
```

You can then make it as complicated as you like!

EDIT: You could pollute the global namespace for this special class...

```
define(['module', 'path', 'crypto'], function(module, path, crypto) {
    window.config = {
        path: path.dirname(module.uri)
        key: crypto.randomBytes(64)
    };
});
```

Add it to the top level require call:

```
require(['config', 'main']);
```

Then you can use it without always adding it to your define:

```
// bar.js
define([], function() {
    var key = config.key;
});
```

Comment: Yeah thats what I have currently, but it means I need to require 'config' from every module. It also means that I cannot specify different configurations for different modules in a centralised manner. I was really hoping to make use of the requireJS config feature, but perhaps it is not possible

Comment: Check out my edit, globals are appropriate if you are using something everywhere

Comment: Ah, true! So hard to tell sometimes :p Your solution only replaces 'config' with 'module' though, in a more convoluted way too. Anywhere you need the config settings you will have to have 'module' in your define. You could use my solution but change window.config = {...} to module.config = {...} (module is really the global namespace in nodejs?)

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on what @jrburke is saying, I found the following pattern to be quite useful: define a config module and it's dependencies in the `main.js` just before the invocation of `require.config()`.

**main.js**

```js
define('config', ['crypto'], function (crypto) {
  return {
    'bar': {
      key: crypto.randomBytes(64)
    },
  };
});

requirejs.config({
  deps: ['app'],
});
```

**app.js**

```js
require(['config'], function (config){

  // outputs value of: crypto.bar.key
  console.log(config.bar.key);
});
```

Plnkr Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/I35bEgaazEAMD0u4cNuj